# Binding Webgrid with Dataset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dataset, webgrid

I am trying to achieve the task of binding a dataset to a webgrid.
As per my knowledge, Webgrid accepts only model as datasource. But I need to acheive it using a dataset. I have created a Dataset property on the model itself.
     Please do guide me. I am a newbie.
     TIA

Comment: Create a view model and map your dataset to it to generate `IEnumerable<yourModel>` so it can be used with WebGrid

Comment: Can you please help me with samples... It will help me much better...

Answer (score 0):

The WebGrid is not able to extract data from a dataset (or more properly, as datatable). You can use [LINQ to DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx) to transform your data an `IEnumerable`. Borrowing the [DataTable example from Dotnet Perls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable), here's how you might do that:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

// Here we add five DataRows.
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

var data = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {
    Dosage = r.Field<int>("Dosage"),
    Drug = r.Field<string>("Drug"),
    Patient = r.Field<string>("Patient"),
    Date = r.Field<DateTime>("Date")
    });
var grid = new WebGrid(data);
```